# Click function not working with all my files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

have a webpage that I've made responsive. When clicking the header I want the meny to drop down. This is currently only working with one of my pages. I have two that looks almost the same. Only difference is that I've included simplecart to the working one. But I feel like that shouldn't matter.

Here is my script where I have the click-function.

```
if(w <= 480){


    $("p").remove(".info");
    $("#sticky_cart").remove();
    $("#copyright").empty();
    $("#sticky_cart_mobile").css("display","block");

    $("dl").each(function(index, value) {
        $(this).css("display","none");
    });

    $(".alternatives").each(function(index, value) {
        $(this).css("display","block");
    });
    $('.categories').on('click',function(){
    //$('.categories').click(function() {
        alert("klick");

        var thisDiv = $(this);
        var theDl = $(this).next("dl");
        var isVisible = theDl.is( ":visible" );

        if (!isVisible) {
            theDl.slideDown("slow");
            thisDiv.addClass("up");
            thisDiv.removeClass("categories");
        }
        else { 
            theDl.slideUp("slow");
            thisDiv.addClass("categories");
            thisDiv.removeClass("up");
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the some of the code it should work with

```
<a name="#pizzakl1" class="category"></a>
                              <section id="pizzakl1">
                                  <h2 class="categories">Pizzor prisklass 1</h2>
                                  <dl>

                                    <?php listPizzaOffline($dbConnection, 1) ?>

                                  </dl>
                              </section>

                              <a name="#pizzakl2" class="category"></a>
                              <section id="pizzakl2">
                                  <h2 class="categories">Pizzor prisklass 2</h2>
                                  <dl>

                                    <?php listPizzaOffline($dbConnection, 2) ?>

                                  </dl>
                              </section>

                              <a name="#pizzakl3" class="category"></a>
                              <section id="pizzakl3">
                                  <h2 class="categories">Pizzor prisklass 3</h2>
                                  <dl>

                                    <?php listPizzaOffline($dbConnection, 3) ?>
```

Why is this not working? Im totally stuck right now.

Comment: Removing and adding the classes later does nothing in regard to which element the event handler is bound to, that's determined by the classes the elements have on pageload.

Comment: What is the output of `w`? Set a breakpoint, if your IDE supports them, otherwise just print the value out somewhere. It may not be what you're expecting. Otherwise we'll need to see more code. What exactly isn't working? Is the problem that the menu isn't dropping down? Can you show us the code (html) for the simplecart?

Comment: The w checks the with of the site so this code only activates when you are on a mobile device. It is the dropdown that is not working. I added an alert to se if the click function works. On my other page everything is working fine but here I don't get the alert so the click event is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding

```
 <section>
      <div id="sticky_cart">
      </div>
 </section>
```

I guess that javascript was confused since I had `$("#sticky_cart").remove();` in my js code and no such element in the html.